# Add conditional formatting on "onedit" through apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to add conditional formatting through the apps script but only for the unique values in the sheet. I have a script that finds if the entered value is unique and a script that adds conditional formatting. now I want to merge both of the scripts in a way that whenever it finds a unique value through oneidt function, it should add conditional formatting for that word. Althrough I have tried to merge both of the scripts but get error `Exception: The parameters (SpreadsheetApp.ConditionalFormatRule) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.setConditionalFormatRules.`

Here is the code

```
// on Edit function that finds unique value in the column
function onEdit(e){
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1){
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    var numRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
    var numCols = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

    var data = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:A"+numRows).getValues();
    var editedCell = e.value;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length;i++){ 
      if (editedCell == data[i] && (i + 2) == e.range.getRow()){
        createRule(editedCell)
        return
      }
    }
  }
}


// Add conditional formatting rule
function createRule(textValues) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet4");

  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
  var backGroundColors = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 0.2)`
  Logger.log(backGroundColors)

  var rules = createConditionalFormatRule(sheet, textValues, backGroundColors)
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}

function createConditionalFormatRule(sheet, textVal, backGroundColor) {  
  var numRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var numCols = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,numRows);
  return SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenTextEqualTo(textVal)
    .setBackground(backGroundColor)
    // .setFontColor(fontColor)
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you check `rules` returned from `createConditionalFormatRule`?  Is it null?

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

The `setConditionalFormatRules()` expects an array of rules.  Modify your script as shown below.

**Script**

```
let rule = createConditionalFormatRule(sheet, textValues, backGroundColors);
let rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
rules.push(rule);
sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

**Reference**

[CondtionalFormatRuleBilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newConditionalFormatRule())